# Xcode Build command ask permission to access the private key from Keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ant, keychain

I am trying the automate the build process of `Xcode` using ant scripts. I used the security import command with -A and -T to import the certificates.

Command which I used to import the certificate

```
security import <PATH till the certificate> -k <PATH of keychain> -t priv -P <password>   -T <codeSigning Path> -T <Xcode.app Path> -A
```

But still when I run the `xcodeBuild` command to archive the build, it pops up a pop which asks for the permission to access the key chain 
[ask for the permission to access the key chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IPFG.png)

Please post as soon as you see this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Working fine

If its default login keychain the above command will work.
If you have created the login keychain then some times code sign will ask for permission.Solution for this restore your login keychain to default version by taking a backup of all the certificates from the login keychain.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well. It seems Mac won't let anything automatically access your keychain. Best solution was to check the "Do this every time" box in the popup to prevent it bothering you again

Comment: Another thing to note: this only worked per project in my case... you'll have to do this for every individual project you wish to automate

Comment: No I cannot use this solution as my ant script is running on a server.So its not possible to login to server and click on always allow pop

Comment: Ouch! Nope then I'm beat! Hope you find the solution quickly